# How to check and replace date values conditionally in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, timestamp

I am working with Python 2.7 and pandas and I have the following dataframe:

```
    col1    col2    col3    date_col
0   123     0       foo     9999-12-31
1   456     1       bar     2017-09-15
2   789     1       psi     9999-12-31
```

When I try to work with this dataframe I get the following error:

> pandas._libs.tslibs.OutOfBoundsDattime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00

I am aware that this is because pandas has a limited window of timestamps it can represent.

**My question is:** How can I replace all the values in the column date_col which are exceeding the bound of the date window with a default value (for example 2000-01-01)? 
Also in my real dataframe I only know the indices of the columns that contain dates, so I *cannot* use the column names.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select column by position with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for replace bad dates to `NaT`s and last [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace to `date`:

Notice - If some bad data like `int` or `str` all are replaced to `NaT`s.

```
date = pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01')
df.iloc[:, 3] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 3], errors='coerce').fillna(date)
print (df)
   col1  col2 col3   date_col
0   123     0  foo 2000-01-01
1   456     1  bar 2017-09-15
2   789     1  psi 2000-01-01
```

Detail:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 3])
0    9999-12-31
1    2017-09-15
2    9999-12-31
Name: date_col, dtype: object

print (pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 3], errors='coerce'))
0          NaT
1   2017-09-15
2          NaT
Name: date_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

Another solution:

```
#http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations
mask = ~df.iloc[:, 3].str.replace('-','').str[:8].astype(int).between(16770921, 22620411)
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: date_col, dtype: bool

df.iloc[:, 3] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 3].mask(mask, '2000-01-01'))
print (df)
   col1  col2 col3   date_col
0   123     0  foo 2000-01-01
1   456     1  bar 2017-09-15
2   789     1  psi 2000-01-01
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been trying to get this to work all afternoon. This works like a charm.

Accepted your answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

df = df.replace({regex of date you want replaced}, {date })

This should work

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html