# How to replace specified datetime with data afterward in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

So this is my dataframe:

```
        dt
0       Apr-14-2012 15:25:49
1       Apr-14-2012 15:38:55
2       Jan-00-0
3       Apr-14-2012 16:05:07
4       Apr-14-2012 16:18:13
```

As you can see, I have invalid datetime. I want to replace the invalid values with data from the next row **but subtracted 3 minutes.**

Here the result:

```
        dt
0       Apr-14-2012 15:25:49
1       Apr-14-2012 15:38:55
2       Apr-14-2012 16:02:07
3       Apr-14-2012 16:05:07
4       Apr-14-2012 16:18:13
```

I have references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935357/how-to-check-and-replace-date-values-conditionally-in-pandas-dataframe) but it's seem only replaced with static values.

Comment: What if there a invalid date on the last row ?

Comment: @Sushanth for my case, there isn't.